# What did you think of Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, winterbash

Aarthi is [looking for feedback regarding the Winter Bash 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161188/what-do-you-think-of-winter-bash) over on Meta Stack Overflow. If you have any comments, complaints, suggestions, or anything else, I'd recommend posting it over there.

Comment: I'd like to keep my Hats from Year to year,It was fun though..

Comment: Too many hats, not enough unicorns

Comment: hats didn't match my gravatar

Answer (score 4):

That was probably the most fun thing the network ever did!